# GetComputedStyle In Ajax Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, getcomputedstyle

I am calling an ajax request with jQuery and the return data contains all html elements. I want to manipulate the styles associated with the response. I have tried DOMParser which gives back the Nodes and seemingly it drops the styles associated with it. I planned to use

```
getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue
```

on the elements but it always returns Null. Are there any ways that I could manipulate the styles in ajax response? I want to get the computed styles on data returned by the ajax or want to know if its even possible?
Thanks

Comment: The browser can't compute styles on elements that aren't rendered in the browser.

Comment: So, is there any way out? How to get style associated with a certain element (ajax response)?

Comment: If it's the computed style you want, you have to add the element to the DOM. If it's just the inline style, get the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The browser can only compute styles after the elements have been added to the DOM, since applicable style rules can depend on an element's position in the DOM. So, no, what you want is not possible.

You could add the elements to the DOM in an unobtrusive way (e.g. off-screen), but you'll have to do so in a way that doesn't affect the properties you want.

Comment: Won't styles be dropped in adding elements to the DOM that way?